# Shared service in Angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing, angular2-services

I'm trying to make a shared service for my app.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class SharedService {
  testService() {
    console.log('share!');
  }
}
```

Then I inject it in my app.component's providers but when I tried to call it in the constructor of a child component like this: `constructor(public sharedService: SharedService) {}` I've got an error: 
`Can't resolve all parameters for MyComponent`. I also tried to inject it in my app.module providers and also got this error. What should I do? How to inject it properly? Can anyone provide an example of proper shared service for antire app(it has several modules)?

I have routing sistem and I want to have a shared service and change it's data from the component which module is currently represented.

Comment: Have you imported `SharedService` in child component?

Comment: No, but wouldn't it just create a new instance on service which isn't a goal of a shared service?

Comment: which version are you using?

Comment: 2.0.1 like @angular

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you use latest version and want to use singleton service.
For that you have to register your service in **`@NgModule({})`** as shown here,

```
import {Sharedservice} from 'valid path';

@NgModule({
   imports:[BroswerModule],
   ...
   providers:[SharedService]
})
```

Now, In child and parent component just import Sharedservice at the top of the file.

NOTE : Remove **`providers:[SharedService]`** from each component.

Comment: provided the correct answer, should be "marked as answer"

Answer (score 0):

You need to set who's the provider for that service with `providers` keyword in `@Component` or `@NgModule` annotation. This is well documented already zilion times, see:

- https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html#!#injector-providers
- https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html#!#providers
- https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html
- https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/dependency-injection.html