# Angular 2 - Subscription to service Subject property doesn't catch events

Tags: angular, rxjs

Here is service:

```
@Injectable() 
export class AuthService {

  public reset: Subject<any>;

  constructor() {
    this.reset = new Subject();
  }

  public logout() {
   this.reset.next('logout');
  }
}
```

This is another service which wants to know when logout() happens:

```
@Injectable()
export class StoreService() {

  constructor(private auth: AuthService) {

    this.auth.changes.subscribe((value) => {
      // Do not work God knows why
    });
  }
}
```

Subscription in the second service will never get any events. Why?

Comment: Sorry, auth.changes is just a getter that returns reset property

Comment: Can you also show how you create `changes` getter (or whatever it is)?

Comment: @Martin Yes, of course, here it is:

`public get changes() {
    return this.reset;
}`

This one I tried too:

`public get changes() {
    return this.reset.asObservable();
 }`

Comment: I'm actually suspicious it has something to do with how you set your `providers`. You might be working with multiple instances of `StoreService`. Maybe have a look at these links: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39958238/shared-service-in-angular2/39958330#39958330

Comment: You might be right, I should check it out

Comment: Ok, AuthService is provided by one module, Store service by another. Both of these modules are included by app.main.module. Anyway, provider for AuthService only one.

Comment: @Martin Thank you, I found a problem. It was two instances of AuthService, really. Easy to catch by adding next to service constructor:

`console.log(\`Create ${counter++} instance of AuthService\`);`

Answer (score 3):

I found the problem - there were multiple instances of AuthService (Thank you @Martin). The problem is if somebody adds provide: [AnyService] to any component, there will be no errors but you will get two (or more) instances of service. 
This kind of bug can be easily found by add `console.log(counter++)` to service constructor.

Answer (score 1):

```
@Injectable() 
export class AuthService {

  public reset: Subject<any>;
  reset$ = null;

  constructor() {
    this.reset = new Subject();
    this.reset$ = this.reset.asObservable();
  }

  public logout() {
   this.reset.next('logout');
  }
}
```

And other service consuming it subscribe to the event.

```
@Injectable()
export class StoreService() {

  constructor(private auth: AuthService) {

    this.auth.reset$.subscribe((value) => {
      console.log(value);
      //implement your own logic here
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: This is actually what I was looking for. Thx!

Answer (score 0):

You have to define Observable string to which you can subscribe in another service or component :

```
@Injectable() 
export class AuthService {

  public reset: Subject<any>;
  /**
   * Observable string streams
   */
  notifyObservable$ = this.reset.asObservable();


  constructor() {
    this.reset = new Subject();
  }

  public logout() {
   this.reset.next('logout');
  }
}
```

// StorageService

```
@Injectable()
export class StoreService() {

  constructor(private auth: AuthService) {

    this.auth.notifyObservable$.subscribe((value) => {
      // Do not work God knows why
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but Subject already returns Observable, why I have to call asObservable() on Observable? Anyway, it still not working

Comment: you can check answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39738974/can-i-emmit-the-event-from-parent-to-child-in-angular2/39739184#39739184 for your reference

Comment: Communication between service and component or between two components through service works excellent but it's not my case. I faced with the situation when one service doesn't get any events from another one. And it doesn't matter what kind of event emitter I use - it can be EventEmitter class or Subject, still not working (