# Global Variable and how pass the value in IONIC3

Tags: javascript, angular, http, typescript, ionic3

I think my problem is very simple, but i'm certainly sothing passing me.

I need to put a TOKEN for the HTTP resquests in a global variable after login.
In my Login page, the HTTP get, return an object with:  HTTP code (200,403,403), a Message("Success") and the TOKEN, and i pass this object to the HOME.ts page true the NavController.

```
this.navCtrl.setRoot(HomePage,{
    data   <<--- Object                        
  });
```

But when i try to put this return "data" in a object of the type "Login"

```
export class Login {

code:number;
token:string;
message:string;

constructor(code?:number, token?:string, message?:string){
    this.code = code;
    this.token = token;
    this.message = message;

}
```

}

To put the atribute Login.token inside the global variable, nothing happen.

I made some test and this is what i have until know.

In the HOME.ts i put some console.log, to figure it out what happen.

```
 console.log(this.navParams.data.data); ----> RESULT 1

console.log(this.navParams.get("data"));    ----> RESULT 2

this.dadosRest = this.navParams.get("data");

console.log(this.dadosRest);  ----> RESULT 3

console.log(this.dadosRest.token); -----> RESULT 4
```

RESULT 1 and 2 and 3:

```
{success: {…}}
```

success
:
code
:
200
message
:
"Welcome admin - This is your token (generated by a previous call)"
token
:
"676f71bab54dad7589c3d1b6b5f5b24de0f8c484"
**proto**
:
Object
**proto**
:
Object

RESULT 3 :

undefined

Why i can't put this return inside the object Login to manage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use globals.
You can use either a [shared service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39958238/shared-service-in-angular2) (create a service that you inject in the components, and them you use a method to store there your token and another one to read the stored value) or store it in some kind of storage (like the [Ionic Storage](https://ionicframework.com/docs/storage/)) or even (and more complicated) use some state container, like Redux.

Anyway: don't pollute the global scope. Maybe you could do this using something like

```
window.token = 'the token'
```

but this is not a good ideia.

Comment: Yeah man, i figure it out how resolve my problem... and i follow your adivise and now i made a shared service! thanks man!